# How do I clear a steroids app from the AppGyver Scanner

Tags: ios, html, cordova, build, steroids

I am attempting to deploy a steroids app to my iphone via the [AppGyver Scanner App](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/appgyver-scanner/id575076515). I am able to generate a QR code and deploy an app one time, after that the deployed app is stuck on the screen and I can't get back to scanner mode so I can deploy a different app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out, you just hold three fingers to the screen...booyah!